# On compilation of The Qlobe

Tags: ruby, web-services, web, quine

I don't know ruby at all,but while reading some another blog I came across this beautiful piece of work [The Qlobe](http://mamememo.blogspot.com/2010/09/qlobe.html).

But I am a windows vista user and I don't have ruby installed in my system,but I am very much inquisitive to enjoy this masterpiece.

So my question is it possible to enjoy this through online compilation? I do tried on [Ideone](http://ideone.com/u1IeA) but it's giving compilation error.